# ResultSet getObject(int, class) with reflection

Tags: java, sql-server, generics, reflection

I am trying to get a value from the result set and then set that value via reflection on a setMethod in a specific class. I am having an issue when my result set comes back with a smallint column in MSSQL and It trys to convert that smallint to a Integer (this is what my set method requires is an int for that pojo).

```
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();
            ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<>(rs.getFetchSize());

            T obj = klass.newInstance();
            CaseInsensitiveMap map = getInsensitiveMethodMap(obj.getClass());
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
                    String columnName = SqlValue.SET_LOWER + md.getColumnName(i);
                    Method m = (Method) map.get(columnName);
//                    Object test = rs.getObject(i, m.getParameterTypes()[0]);
//                    System.out.println(columnName + " " + rs.getObject(i));
                    m.invoke(obj, rs.getObject(i, m.getParameterTypes()[0]));
                }
                results.add(obj);
                obj = klass.newInstance();
            }
            return results;
```

As you can see I am trying to use ResultSet.getObject(Integer, Class) which I am getting the class from the method parameter type. Currently I am getting an error saying "java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported." Is there a way to do this? Be able to dynamically get a specified type value from the result set?

Comment: A JDBC driver is allowed to not implement this method, and even if it is implemented, I don't think it is likely it will support all types of conversions. However, you could just try to use `getObject(int)` instead, as it should return `Integer` for a smallint (I'm assuming the implementation follows the JDBC specification, I haven't checked this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the following is a part of the code I've written for the EasyORM library (github.com/IvanGH2/EasyORM/releases), which pretty much does what you're trying to achieve.

```
   public <T> List<T> getRecordsForSingleTable( Class<? extends DBObject> target, int startRecord, int countRecord,String orderByColumn ) throws EasyORMException {
    T obj=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    AnnotationUtil.checkTableAnnotation(target);
    List<T> objList = new ArrayList<T>();
    countRecord = (countRecord<=0)?recNum:countRecord;
    startRecord = (startRecord<0)?0:startRecord;
    String qualifiedName = dbSchema!=null?dbSchema+"."+target.getAnnotation(TableInfo.class).tableName():target.getAnnotation(TableInfo.class).tableName();
    String query=null;
    if(orderByColumn!=null&&!orderByColumn.isEmpty())
        query=modifyQuery(qualifiedName, startRecord, countRecord, orderByColumn);
    else
        query="SELECT * FROM "+qualifiedName;
    try{
        sqlQuery = query;
        stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            obj = (T) target.getConstructor(ResultSet.class).newInstance(rs);
            ((DBObject)obj).setConnection(conn);
            objList.add(obj);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new EasyORMException(e);
    } finally{
        closeResources(rs,stmt);
    }
    return objList;
}
```

A POJO class should have a constructor accepting a ResultSet (in my implementation, every POJO extends DBObject)

```
//this constructor will be called for whenever creating objects via   reflection from a ResultSet    
 public DBObject(ResultSet rs) throws EasyORMException{
    try{
        for (int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++) {
            Object obj=rs.getObject(i);
            if(obj instanceof Clob){
                cachedResults.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), clobToString((Clob)obj));
            }else if(obj instanceof Blob){
                cachedResults.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), (Blob)obj);
            }else if(obj instanceof String && stringEncoding != null ) {
                try{
                    cachedResults.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), new String(((String)obj).getBytes(stringEncoding),stringEncoding));
                }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                    throw new EasyORMException(e);
                }
            }else{
                cachedResults.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), obj);
            }

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EasyORMException(e);
    }
}
```

And that's basically all you need. Alternatively, have a no-args constructor but create a method that will accept a ResultSet.

Note that cachedResults is a HashMap because my getters/setters use a HashMap (this makes updates a whole lot easier but your implementation can use normal getter/setters that access private member fields)

Comment: Yeah this was the only way I could think of doing this too is using some sort of instanceof and doing the conversions there.